# How to interupt javascript to flush events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function running on document load that copies the contents of a select object to other select boxes (to conserve network bandwidth).

The function is taking a few seconds to complete, so I wanted to mask the main div (to give the user the idea that something is happening).

Unfortunately, the mask is not showing up until after the function completes:

```
    // I want the mask to show immediately here, but never gets shown
    $('#unassignedPunchResults').mask('Getting results');

    $('.employeeList').each(function (i) {
        // this is freezing the browser for a few seconds, the masking is not showing
        $('#employeeList option').clone().appendTo(this);  
    });

    $('#unassignedPunchResults').unmask();
```

How can I interrupt the javascript after the mask() call to flush that event and continue, so the user can see the mask while the longer processing (the each()) processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the rest of the code in a `setTimeout(function() { ...  }, 0)` call.

Comment: @pimvdb: What are you talking about?

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting).

Comment: Read the spec; all that means is that `0` will be increased to `4`.  Writing `0` is more semantically correct.  Also, that's only talking about _successive_ timers; if you're not coming from a timer, `0` will really be `0`.

Comment: Never mind, I interpreted that sentence differently, I'm sorry.

Comment: Same behaviour as before, the mask doesn't show (just in IE8)

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking a while about this. 
The first solution is to use the `settimeout` function.

However it could be a little 'dirty' because you add an arbitrary delay. A more proper logic would be to execute the `$('.employeeList').each(function (i)...` function after the mask function has benne executed and rendered.

Jquery allows us to do that with the deferred functions like [then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) which xecutes after a deferred condition has been satisfied.

So try with:

```
// I want the mask to show immediately here, but never gets shown
    $('#unassignedPunchResults').mask('Getting results').then(function(){

    $('.employeeList').each(function (i) {
        // this is freezing the browser for a few seconds, the masking is not showing
        $('#employeeList option').clone().appendTo(this);  
    });


});
```

In general, using settimeout with an arbitrary number of ms is a solution which works for simple cases, but if you have multiple settimouts in a complex code then you could have synchronizaton problems.

Answer (score 1):

or use a worker, but then you need to discard msie < 10
or break up your calculations in segments that run for less than 500 ms and use setinterval to sread the loading over 5 seconds.
google simulate threading in javascript for code examples.